# How to make complete button process the data ? mean submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

i wanna ask how to make the final step process the data ? , i've tried use form method to redirect process but it not work . i'm using modal-steps.

Already search on stackoverflow but i got nothing, if somebody know how to do it please tellme.

i'm using this wizard https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Wizard-Modal-Bootstrap-jQuery.html

```js
! function(a) {
    "use strict";
    a.fn.modalSteps = function(b) {
        var c = this,
            d = a.extend({
                btnCancelHtml: "Cancel",
                btnPreviousHtml: "Previous",
                btnNextHtml: "Next",
                btnLastStepHtml: "Complete",
                disableNextButton: !1,
                completeCallback: function() {},
                callbacks: {},
                getTitleAndStep: function() {}
            }, b),
            e = function() {
                var a = d.callbacks["*"];
                if (void 0 !== a && "function" != typeof a) throw "everyStepCallback is not a function! I need a function";
                if ("function" != typeof d.completeCallback) throw "completeCallback is not a function! I need a function";
                for (var b in d.callbacks)
                    if (d.callbacks.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
                        var c = d.callbacks[b];
                        if ("*" !== b && void 0 !== c && "function" != typeof c) throw "Step " + b + " callback must be a function"
                    }
            },
            f = function(a) {
                return void 0 !== a && "function" == typeof a && (a(), !0)
            };
        return c.on("show.bs.modal", function() {
            var l, m, n, o, p, b = c.find(".modal-footer"),
                g = b.find(".js-btn-step[data-orientation=cancel]"),
                h = b.find(".js-btn-step[data-orientation=previous]"),
                i = b.find(".js-btn-step[data-orientation=next]"),
                j = d.callbacks["*"],
                k = d.callbacks[1];
            d.disableNextButton && i.attr("disabled", "disabled"), h.attr("disabled", "disabled"), e(), f(j), f(k), g.html(d.btnCancelHtml), h.html(d.btnPreviousHtml), i.html(d.btnNextHtml), m = a("<input>").attr({
                type: "hidden",
                id: "actual-step",
                value: "1"
            }), c.find("#actual-step").remove(), c.append(m), l = 1, p = l + 1, c.find("[data-step=" + l + "]").removeClass("hide"), i.attr("data-step", p), n = c.find("[data-step=" + l + "]").data("title"), o = a("<span>").addClass("label label-success").html(l), c.find(".js-title-step").append(o).append(" " + n), d.getTitleAndStep(m.attr("data-title"), l)
        }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
            var a = c.find("#actual-step"),
                b = c.find(".js-btn-step[data-orientation=next]");
            c.find("[data-step]").not(c.find(".js-btn-step")).addClass("hide"), a.not(c.find(".js-btn-step")).remove(), b.attr("data-step", 1).html(d.btnNextHtml), c.find(".js-title-step").html("")
        }), c.find(".js-btn-step").on("click", function() {
            var m, n, o, p, b = a(this),
                e = c.find("#actual-step"),
                g = c.find(".js-btn-step[data-orientation=previous]"),
                h = c.find(".js-btn-step[data-orientation=next]"),
                i = c.find(".js-title-step"),
                j = b.data("orientation"),
                k = parseInt(e.val()),
                l = d.callbacks["*"];
            if (m = c.find("div[data-step]").length, "complete" === b.attr("data-step")) return d.completeCallback(), void c.modal("hide");
            if ("next" === j) n = k + 1, g.attr("data-step", k), e.val(n);
            else {
                if ("previous" !== j) return void c.modal("hide");
                n = k - 1, h.attr("data-step", k), g.attr("data-step", n - 1), e.val(k - 1)
            }
            parseInt(e.val()) === m ? h.attr("data-step", "complete").html(d.btnLastStepHtml) : h.attr("data-step", n).html(d.btnNextHtml), d.disableNextButton && h.attr("disabled", "disabled"), c.find("[data-step=" + k + "]").not(c.find(".js-btn-step")).addClass("hide"), c.find("[data-step=" + n + "]").not(c.find(".js-btn-step")).removeClass("hide"), parseInt(g.attr("data-step")) > 0 ? g.removeAttr("disabled") : g.attr("disabled", "disabled"), "previous" === j && h.removeAttr("disabled"), o = c.find("[data-step=" + n + "]"), o.attr("data-unlock-continue") && h.removeAttr("disabled"), p = o.attr("data-title");
            var q = a("<span>").addClass("label label-success").html(n);
            i.html(q).append(" " + p), d.getTitleAndStep(o.attr("data-title"), n);
            var r = d.callbacks[e.val()];
            f(l), f(r)
        }), this
    }
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="order" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="js-title-step"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pemesanan/submitorder">
      <div class="row hide" data-step="1" data-title="Detail Pemesanan">
       <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Tanggal Pemesanan</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal_pemesanan" id="tanggal_pemesanan" value="<?php if (empty($this->session->userdata('tanggal_pemesanan'))){
                    echo date('Y-m-d');
                  } else {
                    echo $this->session->userdata('tanggal_pemesanan');
                  } ?>" width="50%">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Closer</label>
                       <select name="id_closer" id="id_closer" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    <option value="">Pilih Closer</option>
                     <?php
              foreach($listcloser->result() as $closer) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $closer->id_closer; ?>" <?php if ($this->session->userdata('id_closer') == $closer->id_closer ) {
                     echo "selected";
                   } ?>><?php echo $closer->nama_closer; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                </div>  
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Pelayanan</label>
                  <input type="text" name="pelayanan" class="form-control" id="pelayanan" placeholder="Pelayanan" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('pelayanan'); ?>">
                </div>
              </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hide" data-step="2" data-title="Data Customer">
    <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="hidden" name="halaman" value="pemesanan">
                <label>Input Customer Baru</label>                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Customer" name="nama_customer" id="nama_customer">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No. HP/WA" name="nohp_wa" id="nohp_wa">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <input maxlength="100" type="text" id="sumber_informasi" class="form-control" placeholder="Sumber Informasi" />
                      </div>
                </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Atau</label><br>
                          <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                          <option value="">Yang sudah ada</option>
                           <?php
                    foreach($listcustomers->result_array() as $cs)
                    {
                      $pilih='';
                      if($cs['id_customer']==$this->session->userdata("id_customer"))
                      {
                        $pilih='selected="selected"';
                        ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $cs['id_customer']; ?>" <?php echo $pilih; ?>><?php echo $cs['nama_customer']; ?></option>
                           <?php
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $cs['id_customer']; ?>"><?php echo $cs['nama_customer']; ?></option>
                          <?php
                      }
                    }
                    ?>
                        </select>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Input Data Anak</label>                
                <div class="form-group">
                 <input maxlength="100" type="text" id="nama_anak" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Anak" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <select id="jenis_kelamin" class="form-control" required="required">
                          <option value="">Pilih Jenis Kelamin</option>
                          <option value="Laki-laki">Laki-laki</option>
                          <option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input maxlength="100" type="date" id="tanggal_lahir" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" class="form-control" />
                      </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Ayah" name="nama_ayah" id="nama_ayah">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Ibu" name="nama_ibu" id="nama_ayah">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input maxlength="100" type="text" id="lahir_di" class="form-control" placeholder="Dilahirkan di" />
                      </div>
            </div>
            <!-- total tagihan -->
           <!-- <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Total Tagihan</label>
                 <span class="pull-right"><h1><?php echo $this->session->userdata('total') ?></h1></span>
                </div>
            </div>-->
            <!-- end-->
  </div>
  <div class="row hide" data-step="3" data-title="Pesanan Hewan">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Data Hewan</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tipe Hewan</label>                  
            <select onchange="hitungpaketaqiqahsatuan()" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="id_paketaqiqah" id="id_paketaqiqah" required>
              <option value="">Pilih Tipe Hewan</option>
              <?php
              foreach($listpaketaqiqah->result_array() as $pa)
              {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $pa['id_paketaqiqah']; ?>"><?php echo $pa['tipe_hewan']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Pilih Kandang</label>                  
            <select onchange="" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="id_kandang" id="id_kandang" required>
              <option value="">Pilih Kandang</option>
                <?php
              foreach($listkandang->result() as $kandang) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $kandang->id_lembaga; ?>"><?php echo $kandang->nama_lembaga; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tanggal Pemotongan</label>
            <input type="date" min="<?php  echo $this->session->userdata('tanggal_pemesanan');//date_format(date_add(date_create($this->session->userdata('tanggal_pemesanan')), date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days')), 'Y-m-d'); ?>" class="form-control pemotongan" name="tanggal_potong" id="tanggal_potong" required >
          </div>
              <div class="form-group">
            <label>Jam Pemotongan</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  type="time" class="form-control pemotongan" name="jam_potong1" id="jam_potong1" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  type="time" class="form-control pemotongan" name="jam_potong2" id="jam_potong2" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Disaksikan/Tidak</label>                
            <select class="form-control pemotongan" style="width: 100%;" name="disaksikan_tidak" id="disaksikan_tidak" required >
              <option value="Disaksikan">Disaksikan</option>
              <option value="Tidak disaksikan">Tidak disaksikan</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Catatan untuk kandang</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Catatan untuk kandang" name="catatan_untuk_kandang" id="catatan_untuk_kandang"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Jumlah</label>
            <input onchange="hitungpaketaqiqahsatuan()"  type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Jumlah" name="jumlah_paketaqiqah" id="jumlah_paketaqiqah" min="1" value="1" required>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Paket Nasi Boks</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Pilih Paket</label>
        <select onchange="hitungpaketnasiboxsatuan()" class="form-control chosen-select" style="width: 100%;" name="id_paketnasibox" id="id_paketnasibox" required>
              <option value="">Pilih</option>
              <?php foreach($listpaketnasibox->result() as $pn) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $pn->id_paketnasibox; ?>"><?php echo $pn->nama_paketnasibox; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label>Jumlah</label>
            <input onchange="hitungpaketaqiqahsatuan()"  type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Jumlah" name="jumlah_paketaqiqah" id="jumlah_paketaqiqah" min="1" value="1" required>
          </div>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Catatan untuk dapur</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Catatan untuk dapur" name="catatan_untuk_dapur" id="catatan_untuk_dapur"></textarea>
          </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="pull-right">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label style="margin-right: 10px">Total Tagihan</label>
                 <span class="" style="margin-right: 10px"><h1>Rp.0</h1></span>
                </div>
            </div>
          -->
  </div>
   <div class="row hide" data-step="4" data-title="Pengantaran">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label> Input Data Pengiriman</label>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Alamat" name="alamat" id="alamat"></textarea>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label >Input URL Gmaps</label>
                 <input type="text" name="urlmaps" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tanggal Pengiriman</label>
                <input type="date" name="tanggal_kirim" class="form-control" min="<?php  echo date_format(date_add(date_create($this->session->userdata('tanggal_pemesanan')), date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days')), 'Y-m-d'); ?>" required>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Jam Kirim</label>
                    <input type="time" name="jam_kirim" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Jam Sampai</label>
                    <input type="time" name="jam_sampai" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Tarif / Ongkos</label>
                <input type="number" name="ongkos" class="form-control" min="0">
              </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                <label>Petugas Pengantaran</label>
                <?php foreach ($listdelivery->result() as $ld) { ?>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <input type="radio" class="radiopetugaspengantaran" name="petugas_pengantaran"  value="<?php echo $ld->id_lembaga;?>">
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ld->nama_lembaga;?>" readonly>
                     <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <input type="radio" class="radiopetugaspengantaran" name="petugas_pengantaran" value="Lainnya">
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="petugas_pengantaran" name="petugas_pengantaran_teks" value="Lainnya" disabled>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Total Tagihan</label>
                 <span class="pull-right"><h1>Rp. 0</h1></span>
                </div>-->
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hide" data-step="5" data-title="Pembayaran dan Tagihan">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Diskon</label>
                  <input type="number" min="0" onkeyup="hitungtotaldansisa()" onchange="hitungtotaldansisa()" class="form-control" placeholder="Diskon" name="diskon" id="diskon" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('diskon'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>DP</label>
                  <input type="number" min="0" onkeyup="hitungtotaldansisa()" onchange="hitungtotaldansisa()"  class="form-control" placeholder="DP" id="dp" name="dp" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('dp'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Mekanisme Pembayaran</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="mekanisme_pembayaran" name="mekanisme_pembayaran">
                    <option value="TUNAI" <?php if ($this->session->userdata('mekanisme_pembayaran') == "TUNAI" ) {
                     echo "selected";
                   } ?>>Tunai</option>
                   <option value="TRANSFER" <?php if ($this->session->userdata('mekanisme_pembayaran') == "TRANSFER" ) {
                     echo "selected";
                   } ?>>Transfer</option>
                 </select>
               </div>  
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Sisa</label>
                 <span class="pull-right"><h2>Rp. 0</h2></span>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Total Tagihan</label>
                 <span class="pull-right"><h2>Rp. 0</h2></span>
                </div>
            </div>
              </div>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-btn-step pull-left" data-orientation="cancel" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning js-btn-step" data-orientation="previous"></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success js-btn-step" data-orientation="next"></button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more button below the next button. Keep that button hidden till you reach the last step. When you reach the last step make it visible and on click of it write the logic to process your data.

Comment: Any example for to do that? because i new in javascript

Comment: Can you provide runnable example of your code e.g. code pen, jsfiddle?

Comment: same like this bro https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Wizard-Modal-Bootstrap-jQuery.html

Comment: Use completeCallback function where you have initialized wizard. When you will click on complete it will call this function so within this function you can write your logic to submit data. Line number 11 in your above JavaScript code. For example I have added alert, so when it is in last step and I click complete it will show message submitted E.g. completeCallback: function() {alert("Submitted");}

Comment: yeah works.
now i need to process the data from modal what should i do now? 
using form method or this window.location.href = " " ?

Comment: Now you can read the value from each control, create data object in required data format and call your api using ajax to submit data. You can read control value using ID as $("#pelayanan").val()

Comment: Ok thanks for help ! now i'm going to submit the data  :)

Comment: All the best 

Comment: did u have t*elegram account bro?